# Static in limbs

Tags: human-biology

I have noticed that while sitting in the Sukhasan posture(picture below) for a long time, my feet suddenly become all stiff and i am unable to move it. What I deduce from the experience is that it is static, though I fail to understand how it accumulated at my feet.Does anyone have an explanation for this?
[image: Sukhasan Posture]

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "static." Are you describing paresthesia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea how "static" comes into this, do you mean static electricity? Why would that be related?

Anyway, what you are probably experiencing is simple numbness caused by your posture applying pressure to a nerve:

[image]

In the image above, the right leg is likely to be pressing the the left which can cause [paresthesia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paresthesia), more commonly known as "pins and needles". As explained in the NIH's [paresthesia information page:](http://www.ninds.nih.gov/disorders/paresthesia/paresthesia.htm)

> Most people have experienced temporary paresthesia -- a feeling of "pins and needles" -- at some time in their lives **when they have sat with legs crossed for too long**, or fallen asleep with an arm crooked under their head. It happens when sustained pressure is placed on a nerve. The feeling quickly goes away once the pressure is relieved.

Comment: it feels as if my leg is brimming with static electricity but i guess your explanations sums it up...

Comment: When I sleep more on one side I get more pain than tingling. But not only that but the pain is close and prolonged as if my muscles have been injured.