# Why do our limbs and other body parts get numb/feelingless and then they start to tickle?

Tags: human-biology

Why do our limbs (legs, arms) get numb/feelingless when they are under prolonged pressure or when one has crossed his/her leg while sitting for a long period?

After we move it to a more relaxed or natural position numbness goes away and we get the really strange and hard to bear tickles. Why does the numbness go away by doing this and why do why get these odd tickles?

Comment: [This other post](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/13893/static-in-limbs) should answer your question (The question had been quite poorly asked I think but well answered!)

Comment: It doesn't elaborate the needle sensation and for another it not always happens because of apparent pressure, like I stated, if one keeps his/her legs crossed (like [this](http://www.sciencealert.com.au/images/stories/Warren_Goldswain_CrossLeg_shutterstock.jpg)) even than the foot on the top gets numb.

Comment: Keeping feet crossed like in your picture, involves pressure on nerves in both the legs. If one leg applies pressure on the other, it feels the same amount of pressure. (Newton's third law)